# Is it possible to define a non-generic interface which can have generic methods?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I was wondering if this code could be improved.  The IProvider implements IProvider and overwrites Request(...).  I'd like to combine these into a single interface.  But I still need a typed and untyped interface to work with.

Is there a way to combine these where I get both or is this how the interfaces should look?

```
public interface IProvider
{
    DataSourceDescriptor DataSource { get; set; }

    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    IResult Request(IQuery request);
}

public interface IProvider<T> : IProvider
{
    new IResult<T> Request(IQuery request);
}
```

Comment: I followed you guys instructions and that worked as I wanted.  I can only give 1 winner. sorry.

Comment: Next time around you might want to double check "oldest" there boss.

Comment: you edited yours after his which is why he gets the check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the generic type parameter `T` is only relevant in the context of the `Request` method, declare only that method as generic:

```
public interface IProvider
{
    DataSourceDescriptor DataSource { get; set; }

    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    IResult Request(IQuery request);

    IResult<T> Request<T>(IQuery request);
}
```

Comment: Whoever voted me down: It is useless, if you don't explain, why you did it! Especially, after the answer has already been accepted...!

Comment: I think it was VulgarBinary...  He was going off about how his answer should have been picked and now his rant is deleted.  I guess another member could have just removed his unnecessary comments though - not sure.

Comment: @VulgarBinary: Sorry for suspecting it was you.

Comment: Removing that post due to inappropriate content.  Just frustrated with the current rate of abandoned questions I'm sitting on and the fact I got knocked w/o a comment really agitates me.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth   It's the same reason I left Experts Exchange, at least they had a moderator clean up process where questions were force accepted upon being abandoned... I figured stack with the entirely community driven content would be different... At this rate I might just go back to EE.

Comment: @VulgarBinary: Most of the reputation on SO is earned through upvoted answers, not through accepted ones. AFAIK, that's very different from - and better than - EE.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the capability to execute untyped code you cannot put that method inside a generic class (and have it still make sense design wise).  So the answer is no... what you have is the correct approach when you need untyped and typed interfaces.

However you can have a reference to the initial interface or roll them all into a single interface, but your untyped methods will still have to be declared inside a generic class, ie:

```
ObjectProvider<SomeObjectType> j = new ObjectProvider<SomeObjectType>();
j.DataSource = //Do something
```

Now, you could always specify Request as a generic method and allow both to exist in the same context...  but... That is in the end up to you.

```
public interface IProvider
{
    IResult<T> Request<T>(IQuery request);

    DataSourceDescriptor DataSource { get; set; }

    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    IResult Request(IQuery request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, implementing the interface means you are leaving the base interface's members in child too - inheritance works this way of course.

So, what will happen when you implement your child (generic) interface by some class? Of rouse you will get both generic and non-generic members in the implementor class, which is not exactly what you want as I understand.

Solution:

1. declare base interface (e.g. IProviderBase) containing "Datasource" and "Configuration" members only.
2. make IProvider the child of IProviderBase and declare non-generic Request() in it.
3. make IProvider<T> the child of IProviderBase and declare generic Request<T>() in it.

Makes sense?